# PGM winsock2 failure to create socket

Tags: windows, winsock, winsock2, pgm-protocol

I just found out about PGM (Pragmatic General Multicast) in windows sockets. I read up on msdn how to configure a send and receive socket but it's not working.

This is the code so far:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <wsrm.h>



int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    DWORD dwRet = NO_ERROR;

    WSADATA wsa_data;
    if( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 0 ), &wsa_data ) != 0 ) {
        dwRet = GetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return dwRet;
    }

    SOCKET        s;
    SOCKADDR_IN   salocal, sasession;
    int           dwSessionPort;

    s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RDM, IPPROTO_RM );

    if( s == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        dwRet = GetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return dwRet;
    }

    salocal.sin_family = AF_INET;
    salocal.sin_port   = htons (0);    // Port is ignored here
    salocal.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

    int iRet = bind (s, (SOCKADDR *)&salocal, sizeof(salocal));

    if( iRet == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {

        dwRet = GetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return dwRet;
    }

    dwSessionPort = 0;
    sasession.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sasession.sin_port   = htons (dwSessionPort);
    sasession.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("234.5.6.7");

    connect (s, (SOCKADDR *)&sasession, sizeof(sasession));

    return dwRet;
}
```

I get error code 10044 (Socket type not supported) when i try to create the socket. How do I enable the use of PGM?

I'm currently working on Windows 7 with MSMQ installed.

**EDIT**
This is the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) site I read up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the MSMQ wasn´t properly installed. In order for it to include all features (Multicast Support) all the subfolders had to be explicitly checked as shown in the picture below.

[image]